# CPU reading cycles.

Tags: computer-architecture, memory-access

Assume the CPU has 64 data lines. Then Z reading cycles will be
needed to load an array of 12 double-precision floating-point numbers,
each number coded in eight bytes, from the main memory into the CPU.
Z = ?

So I'm looking at some of the past exam questions to prepare for my exams next year and this question (above) has stumped me. I genuinely don't know how to work this out. I know that a 64 bit machine is a lot faster than a 32 bit one but that's about it. Can anyone explain this? (Assume I am an idiot please)

Comment: "I know that a 64 bit machine is a lot faster than a 32 bit one but that's about it." -- that's wrong. One has little if anything to do with the other. This question is impossible to answer without knowing what CPU architecture you're referring to.

Comment: If it has 64 data lines, it can load a double (= 64 bits) in one read cycle, so it should need 12.

Comment: Are you sure your question is copied accurately. I am no specialist, but on the net it seems that people talk of "data line" in the singular,  and of $n$-bit data line. See this [question answered by a hardware person](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21772276). Telling us the level of your exam might also tell us what level of sophistication is needed to answer. What course is it, for what kind of curriculum.

Answer (score 1):

a **double precision floating-point**, is a 64-bit variable (as the question says: 8 bytes each = 64 bits).

If the CPU's bus width is 64bit, and assuming the memory has a data width of 64-bit, then exactly 12 read-cycles are needed to read 12 double-float variables, since at each cycle we can access 64-bits = 1 complete variable.

If, however, the memory has a data-width of 8 bits (every address gives back only 8 bits of data), then 1 double-float variable lays over 8 different addresses, and takes 8 cycles to read. Then, to read 12 different variables, the CPU needs to access 96 different addresses, i.e., 96 read-cycles.

If the parameters of the CPU/Memory are different, so does the answer.